# Detecting .exe files embedded in .xls files

Tags: microsoft-excel, email, malware

We have recently received several emails in which an .exe is embedded in an .xls file. The emails are clearly junk and we delete them when we see they're bad. However the only way to filter these emails before they get to the end user is to filter out all .xls files. Our company uses quite a few excel documents throughout the day.

Is there a way to detect that an .xls has an embedded .exe file and then filter only those emails? We use the SurfControl email filter.

Comment: Can you instead perhaps filter based on who sent it? How large is the .exe, did it make the file some abnormal size?  If your company uses excel files a lot, I assume there's some way to determine where it's from (like the user's email ends in @mycompany.com)?

Comment: I think that the method used to embed it probably has some bearing. Is "foo.xls.exe" ? Embedded = encoded as base64 and then a macro runs to save it out to disk? embedded = inserted object?

Comment: We already let all inside emails through no matter the attachments. And the only extension is .xls.

Comment: (1) Note that if a file is named `foo.xls.exe`, depending on your settings, it might only show you `foo.xls` even though it as a `.exe` at the end (2) any reason it can't be filtered by sender or sender domain? (3) route your external mail  through an email security gateway provider which would scan all emails that go through it and remove malicious attachments

Comment: we could filter it that way but we get these files from several different servers and email addresses

Comment: Does using .xlsx format prevent embedded binary files?  If so, block .xls files and allow .xlsx.  Educate your customers to use the correct format.0

Comment: An xlsx is a zip file wit andere other extensie,  so you could try to unzip it. I don't know uf such a thing could be done with xls.